# Change value to array for c++ and saving file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to simply change a value to an array and then to write that array to a file and save it. Here is my code:

```
void changePrices(float prices[15])
{
    int row;
    string filename = "rowPrices.dat";
    ofstream inFile(filename);

    cout << "Enter in the row: ";
    cin >> row;
    int rownumber = row - 1;
    cout << "Enter in the new price: ";
    float price;
    cin >> price;
    cout << price << endl;
    price = prices[rownumber];
    for (int i = 0; i < rowvalue; i++)
    {
        inFile << prices[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << prices[rownumber];

    ifstream save(filename);
}
```

However, my `price` variable is not being written to the array value (in this case `prices[rownumber]`). I simply try to assign the floating variable to the array, but it simply is not being overwritten. Additionally, I want that file to be saved using some kind of save function. Is it working properly? How can I overwrite my variable to the array value? Note: the array is a float.

Comment: Because the shown code fails to meet all requirements for a [mre], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help], it is unlikely that anyone will be able to help you. For more information, see [ask] questions.

Comment: Sidenote: You are using a type that is unnecessarily complicated for the task at hand. `std:vector<float>` will make everything easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not changing the array, you are copying a value from the array to `price`, effectively overwriting what the user entered.

```
price = prices[rownumber];
```

should be

```
prices[rownumber] = price;
```

Comment: Don't forget to close the file explicitly once you are done writing to it.

Comment: @Bhawan you don't need to close the file. It's done in the destructor at the end of the function. It's called RAII